# Spring Autowiring and Class Inheritance

Tags: spring, inheritance, autowired

I'm having a problem getting @Autowired to work.  Sorry if I screw up any terms, I am relatively new to Spring.

Spring Version is 3.0.5.RELEASE, and I am using context:component-scan in my beans definition.

This works with the @Autowired annotation:

```
@Component
public class UserDao {
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public User findById(Long id) {
        return em.find(User.class, id);
    }
}
```

This does NOT work with the @Autowired annotation:

```
@Component
public class UserDao implements Dao<User> {
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public User findById(Long id) {
         return em.find(User.class, id);
    }
}
```

With this setup, **all I've added 'implements Dao'**, and I get a:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [web.rs.persistence.dao.UserDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

And here are some other classes for reference:

Dao.java (interface):

```
public interface Dao<T extends BaseEntity> {
    T findById(Long id);
}
```

UserResource.java:

```
@Component
public class UserResource {
    @Autowired
    UserDao userDao;

    public User getUser(Long id) {
        return userDao.findById(id);
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

        <context:component-scan base-package="web.rs" />

        <bean id="placeholderConfig" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location" value="classpath:config.properties" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
                <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver" />
            </property>
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${persistence.unit}" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="trx-manager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
        </bean>

        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="trx-manager" />
    </beans>
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?  I'd love to keep class inheritance.

Thanks!

Comment: have you defined the bean in your context file ? If you have multiple bean of UserDao then try using `@qualifier` along with `@autowire`

Comment: There is only one UserDao in the classpath, and I am using <context:component-scan base-package="web.rs" /> in my beans file.

Comment: as you are getting `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` it seems you havnt defined the bean in the context file.Can you please post your context file

Comment: Posted.  I've tried it with AND without `<bean id="userDao" class="web.rs.persistence.dao.UserDao"/>` with no luck.  Remember that ONLY adding the interface made it break.

Comment: Try using @ Repository instead of @ Component also check for the root exception or is this the only exception in your log?

Comment: Posted in the post is the root exception.  Adding `@Repository` caused the same exception (I added it on the `UserDao` class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using the @Transactional annotation, Spring creates a JDK proxy when the class implements an interface. In your case, the JDK proxy of (UserDao implements Dao<User>) will implement Dao<User> but will not extend UserDao. Therefore, the bean in the context will be a Dao<User>.

When the class with the @Transaction annotation doesn't implement an interface, Spring must create a CGLIB proxy that extends UserDao. Therefore, the bean in the context will be a UserDao.

You can tell Spring to always use CGLIB proxies when putting this in your applicationContext.xml :

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="trx-manager" proxy-target-class="true" />
```

There are some drawbacks but I don't remember them.

I don't use proxy-target-class="true" and my design is like this :

I have an interface for every type of Dao.

```
 public interface UserDao extends Dao<User>

   List<User> findByUsername();
```

I implement the specific interface

```
 @Component
 public class UserDaoJpa implements UserDao

   public List<User> findByUsername() {
     ...
   }
```

My service classes uses the UserDao :

```
 public class UserService {

   @Autowired
   private UserDao userDao;
 }
```

The bean in the context is a UserDaoJpa and it will be inject where a UserDao is used.

Comment: When I try your suggestion, I get a the following exception: `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [web.rs.persistence.dao.UserDao]: Specified class is an interface` ... any suggestions? (NOTE: I didn't go the route of `proxy-target-classes`)

Comment: If you are using the component-scan, is the @Component annotation on the UserDaoJpa class? Otherwise, you have to create the bean this way : <bean id="userDao" class="web.rs.persistence.dao.UserDaoJpa"/>. You must not have this : <bean id="userDao" class="web.rs.persistence.dao.UserDao"/> because it will try to instantiate an interface

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to autowire the `Dao` interface (rather than the `UserDao`) in your `UserResource` class, e.g.

```
@Component
public class UserResource {
    @Autowired
    Dao<User> userDao;

    // ...
}
```

If you have several implementations of the `Dao` interface, you must tell Spring which is the appropriate one, for example by using the `@Qualifier` annotation.