# Spring can not set dao bean in controller

Tags: spring, hibernate, dependency-injection, hibernate-generic-dao

I'm trying to inject a dao-bean in my controller from spring MVC. I'm using the generic dao pattern for the dao-objects.

For an unknown reason I receive this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'klantController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private service.KlantDao controllers.KlantController.klantDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [service.KlantDao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

This is the generic dao interface:

```
package service;

import java.util.List;

public interface GenericDao<T> {

    public List<T> findAll();
    public T update(T object);
    public T get(Long id);
    public void delete(T object);
    public void insert(T object);
    public boolean exists(Long id) ;
}
```

The generic dao class:

```
package service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Transactional
public class GenericDaoJpa<T> implements GenericDao<T> {

    private Class<T> type;
    private EntityManager em;

    public GenericDaoJpa(Class<T> type) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public T get(Long id) {
        T entity = this.em.find(this.type, id);
        return entity;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return this.em.createQuery(
                "select entity from " + this.type.getName() + " entity").getResultList();
    }

    //@Transactional
    @Override
    public void insert(T object) {
        em.persist(object);
    }

    //@Transactional
    @Override
    public void delete(T object) {
        em.remove(em.merge(object));
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public boolean exists(Long id) {
        T entity = this.em.find(this.type, id);
        return entity != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T update(T object) {
        return em.merge(object);
    }
}
```

The concrete DAO I'm try to inject:

```
package service;
import domain.Klant;

public class KlantDao extends GenericDaoJpa<Klant>
{
    public KlantDao()
    {
        super(Klant.class);
    }
}
```

The controller class where I'm trying to inject the bean:

```
@Controller
public class KlantController 
{
    @Autowired
    private KlantDao klantDao;

// route methods

    public KlantDao getKlantDao() {
        return klantDao;
    }

    public void setKlantDao(KlantDao klantDao) {
        this.klantDao = klantDao;
    }
}
```

In the dispatcher servlet I configure the bean like this:

```
<bean id="klantDao" class="service.KlantDao"/>
```

I think the problem is something with the autowiring. I've tried a lot of combinations of settings but I always receive the same error.

I hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: There is no bean of the type `KlantDao` in the context, this is due to proxies which is springs aop mechanism. There is a bean of type `GenericDao<Klant>` and not of `KlantDao`. I strongly suggest the use of [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) that way you can remove the code of the `GenericDao` and saves you a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: There are missing information on your question; such as wiring mechanism through annotations or mere XML configuration? Version of Spring? I believe this should be fixed with `proxy-target-class=true`. (Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9120104/248082)

Answer (score 0):

Your  code   is  right  but you need to add @Services KlantDao

Comment: Where do I have to add @Services? I don't understand your answer.